# Excel-VBA .Range("NamedRange").Row Returning a Different Row Then Where Range is Located

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following the named range in Excel.

[image]

I also have the following code that works with that named range:

```
With wsVehicleSummary

With .Range(.Cells(.Range("VehicleList").Row, 1), .Cells(.Range("VehicleList").Row, .Range("K1").Column)).Offset(1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Resize(.Range("VehicleList").End(xlDown).Row - .Range("VehicleList").Row, 11).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    .Resize(.Range("VehicleList").End(xlDown).Row - .Range("VehicleList").Row, 11).Sort "Veh #", xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

The issue arises in the Remove Duplicates call and I've narrowed it to down to the fact that `.Range("VehicleList").Row` is equating to 40, when it should be 20 (as can be seen in screenshot).

I have debugged this at run-time and am baffled why `?.Range("VehicleList").Row` is returning 40 instead of 20.

Although, as I write this, I wonder if it has to do with how I called range in the With block and how I use Resize.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: You're applying the .Range to another .Range and not the worksheet. Store the row number in a variable at the start and just refer to that.

Comment: Thanks @Rory. I think I see what you're saying. Probably placing a variable in there will make it easier to read and maintain too! Sometimes I get too crafty for my own good :)

Comment: or you could use `.Parent.Range(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611989/rory)'s comment, I made the following changes and my code now works as expected.

```
With wsVehicleSummary

    Dim lRowResize As Long
    lRowResize = .Range("VehicleList").End(xlDown).Row - .Range("VehicleList").Row

    With .Range(.Cells(.Range("VehicleList").Row, 1), .Cells(.Range("VehicleList").Row, .Range("K1").Column))
        .Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Resize(lRowResize, 11).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
        .Resize(lRowResize, 11).Sort "Veh #", xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
```